# Multiple SQL queries, one per ID

Tags: sql, mysql, scala

`ids` contains 100 `ids` that are comma delimited.  Is it fine or does it need improvement?

```
 def getFriendPoints(ids: String) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      try {
        var pointMap:scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]=Map()
        var i=ids.split(",")
        for(pos<-0 to i.size){
        val result = SQL("SELECT  point,privacy FROM `tableName` WHERE id={user}").on("user" -> i(pos)).apply().head
        val point = if (result[Boolean]("privacy")) { result[Double]("point").toString } else { "0" }
        pointMap+=("id"+pos -> i(pos), "point" -> point)
        }
        pointMap
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          Map("result" -> "error")
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Am I missing something? You declare pointMap as null then try to call a method on it. How does this ever not return error?

Comment: Daenyth it was Map()  sorry wrong code updated,

Comment: Trying to subvert using the `IN` clause by using a loop is a pretty bad idea, especially given a solution to use `IN`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339011/mysql-query-in-clause-at-playframework

Answer (score 10):

*Preamble: I don't know scala. All code you see here is improvised from the question and a few bits of scala that I've seen somewhen. Improvements and comments are welcome*

#### Naming:

I am going to be blunt here... Your names are **bad**. Not horrible, but ***seriously bad***.

> ```
> var i = ids.split(",");
> ```

first thing jumping me here is, that you have a single thing (the id-string) named with a plural. next thing that jumps me, is that you have a collection with multiple elements and it's name is **a single letter**.

Rename that stuff:

> ids -> idString
> i -> idCollection (or even ids, anything is better...)

on we go:

> ```
> for(pos<-0 to i.size){
> ```

usually the iterator in a for loop has your single letter identifier, extremely often, that is our friend `i`. Also you don't really have to cramop that all together. Give your variables and statements some fresh air:

```
for (i <- 0 to idCollection.size) {
```

looks much more readable IMO ;)

> ```
> val result = SQL([...]
> ```

result is a dumb name. result of what? yes, I know it's the SQL statment, but if you just skim it, you could think it's what you want to return in the end.

instead I'd use `dbRecord` or similar.

Alright, so much for the names, now we get to the **real wtf**

#### Storing numbers:

***WHY DO YOU STORE NUMBERS AS STRINGS?

AND WHY DO YOU STORE POINTS IN A SEPARATE ENTRY?*** <sub>pardon caps</sub>

Don't shoehorn everything into Strings:

```
var pointMap:scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double]=null
[...]
val point:Double = if (result[Boolean]("privacy")) {
    result[Double]("point")
} else {
    0.0
}
pointMap+=("id" + idCollection(i) -> point)
```

Answer (score 7):

Combine this with andrey's answer about using the `IN` operator to get back a Stream of results (this is Play framework, right?), then map that to another Stream and convert to a Map.  Good scala practice is to use vals not vars.

Also I don't think you were building the map you wanted to build.  It looks like you wanted to associate an id with a point value, but I think you ended up with a map with many ("id#" -> "someId") entries and one ("point" -> "123") that got overwritten many times and wasn't associated with any id.

```
def getFriendPoints(ids: String) = {
  val users=ids.split(",")
  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    try {
      val results = SQL("SELECT  point,privacy, id FROM `tableName` WHERE id IN ({users})").onList("users" -> users)
      results().map( result =>
        val id = result[String]("id")
        val point = if (result[Boolean]("privacy")) { result[Double]("point").toString } else { "0" }
        (id -> point)
      ).toMap  //toMap if you want a Map instead of a Stream
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        Map("result" -> "error")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

100 queries is not fine! It's slow. For each select statement there is a significant overhead required to set up and run the query.

Instead you should use a **single** SELECT statement with a better WHERE clause:

```
SELECT point, privacy FROM `tablename` WHERE id IN (_set_)
```

for more information [read up on the IN operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: Wouldn't this method be open to injection though?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Try function which is a convenient/compact alternative to writing your useful code inside try/catch (noise) block! The other salient points have been covered by earlier responses, namely using the IN clause in SQL, preferring vals over vars and pattern matching:

```
import scala.util.Try

def getFriendPoints(ids: String): Map[String, String] = {
  val users = ids.split(",")

  def pointsById(users: Array[String]): Map[String, String] = {
    val rows = SQL("SELECT point, privacy, id FROM `tableName` where id IN ({users}}").onList("users"->users)
    rows.map { row =>
      val id = result[String]("id")
      val point = result[Boolean]("privacy") match {
        case true  => result[Double]("point").toString
        case false => "0"      
      }
      (id -> point)
    }
  }

  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    Try(pointsById(users)).getOrElse(Map("result"=>"error"))
  }
}
```

Here'a another way, getFriendPoints returns a type Try[Map[String, Double]]. There is not need to make the value type in the Map a String, just to return an error string!:

```
import scala.util.Try

def getFriendPoints(ids: String): Try[Map[String, Double]] = {
  // contents remain the same


  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    Try(pointsById(users)))
  }
}

// Your client code
getFriendPoints(" ... ").getOrElse(Map("Error"->"Message"))
```